# rounding to 2 decimal points on a specific column

Tags: awk, rounding, decimal-point

I have a list like this:

```
Cond1 4 0.2343
Cond2 10 1.765
Cond3 8 1.9234
```

I am trying to round the value in the 3rd column to 2 decimal points, so that it will look like this:

```
Cond1 4 0.24
Cond2 10 1.77
Cond3 8 1.92
```

I know that there is a way to do this in awk, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `%.2f` modifier for `printf` or `sprintf()`:

```
$ awk '{printf "%s %s %.2f\n",$1,$2,$3}' file
```

or

```
$ awk '{$3=sprintf("%.2f",$3)}1' file
```

Output:

```
Cond1 4 0.23
Cond2 10 1.76
Cond3 8 1.92
```

More, for example, here:

https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Format-Modifiers.html

Comment: Beware that using `printf/sprintf` this way might in certain circumstances give different result (*unbiased* vs *naive*) on different machines - see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Round-Function.html

Comment: And the `sprintf("%.2f")` also changes the `typeof($3)` (`typeof()` function is GNU awk only) from strnum to string and man I debugged that old code for a long time after some changes.

Comment: What does the '1' in '{$3=sprintf("%.2f",$3)}1' do?! Seems to be necessary, but changing it to anything but 0 doesn't affect results. 

Comment: @Unknown 1 - or any non-zero value - evaluates to true which in awk means to output the current record.